# Multiple author in org-mode latex export

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

I write a lot of files in org-mode of Emacs which is awesome.
I started to do writing of scientific papers in org-mode.
But: the article has several authors.

I used

```
#+AUTHOR: Author 1, Author 2
```

It exports to Latex correctly.

However, I need emails and institutions of the authors. 
Can I do it directly in org-mode?

the command

```
#+EMAIL: email1, email2
```

picks the last one.

Answer (score 3):

```
#+EMAIL: email@foo.uk, email@bar.uk
```

works correctly here (Org 7.8.09).

Comment: Confirmed. My somewhat out of date `M-x org-version` 7.8.03 exports `Name 1, Name 2` with a footenote of `email 1, email 2` on the first page.